# Is LR(2) parser a subset of LL(3)?

Tags: parsing, lr-grammar, ll-grammar

I'm asked if LL(3) is a subset of LR(2) and vice versa.

I succeeded to prove that LL(3) is not a subset of LR(2):

In LL(3) we can recognize the rule after reading 3 characters past the beginning.

In LR(2) we can recognize the rule after reading 2 characters past the end.

Thus, say the rule is empty (upsilon) then LL(3) would give us more information than LR(2) would. Therefor, LL(3) is not contained within LR(2).

How do I prove the other way?

Comment: Are they sets of LR(2)/LL(3) languages or sets of LR(2)/LL(3) grammars?

Comment: For languages, LL(3) is a strict subset of LR(2)...

Comment: It's more a question for cs.stackexchange, not stack overflow :)

Answer (score 1):

This https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/48 states that none of these sets of languages are subset of other.

Upd: actually it states that LL(3) is subset of LR(2), sorry.

Comment: it actually says LL ⊂ LR(1) , and it also mentioned LR(1)=LR(k)=LR , thus LL IS contained in LR

Comment: Indeed, last sentence was about LL(*), not LL.

Comment: OK, And do you think LR(2) could be a subset of LL(3) as well?

Comment: It's ok, the answer is no, i finally found it in some website. Thank you

Comment: According to the statement, LR is clearly a superset of LL(k), so now you are asking if LR(2) is subset of LL(k), which can only be possible if they are the same sets. Which is obviously wrong → LR(k) is not subset of LL(k)

Answer (score 0):

According to the slides from my compiler construction course.

LR(k) = LR(1) is a superset of any LL(k)

Therefore, LR(2) or LR(1) is superset of LL(3) or any LL(k)

Look at picture from the link.
[Languages diagram. LR(k), LL(k)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHjTE.png)

I can not prove it, but it's clear that LR(k) | k >= 1, is more powerful, than LL(k) | any k, because LL(k) doesn't support left-recursive grammars. It is still not a proof, though